# How to get the value of a column and cell data?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a button "btnSetAppointment", I created a Scheduling system, and when I save an appointment it will automatically send a message to the patient's `phone_number`. However, I don't know how to get the value of `phone_number` from the table.

As you can see below, I declared number as string, I want to store the `phone_number` of a patient in the database.

```
Private Sub btnSetAppointment_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSetAppointment.Click
                'SMS

 query = "SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE Phone_Number =" & frmViewSchedule.dgvSchedule.SelectedRows(3).Cells(0).Value
                cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, MySqlConn)
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                Dim number1 As String

                If reader.HasRows Then
                    number1 = frmViewSchedule.dgvSchedule.SelectedRows(3).Cells(0).Value


                    With SerialPort1
                        .Write("at" & vbCrLf)
                        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
                        .Write("at+cmgf=1" & vbCrLf)
                        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
                        .Write("at+cmgs=" & Chr(34) & number1 & Chr(34) & vbCrLf)
                        .Write(sys_msg & Chr(26))
                        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
                        MsgBox(rcvdata.ToString)

                    End With
                End If
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it using MySQL (after establishing a database connection).

```
         Try
            Dim MyDb As New Database_Connection
            Dim query As String
            query = "select phone_number from schedule where Phone_Number = '" & frmViewSchedule.dgvSchedule.SelectedRows(3).Cells(0).Value & "'"
                Dim myReader As OdbcDataReader = MyDb.ExecuteQuery(query)

            myReader.Read()

             If reader.HasRows Then
               dim ph_number as string = myReader.Item(0)
              .
              .
              .
             End if             
                myReader.Close()
                MyDb.Dispose()
            Catch ex As System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException
                'MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
            End Try
```

Comment: i changed the code like this because I'm using MySql database